# QSettings not saving ini changes without admin privileges

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ini, qsettings

### Problem

I am currently learning Qt by writing a mp3 player on Windows. Now I want to use `QSettings` to save changes made to the application. I already tried saving the changes to the registry (which works fine) but I would like to store them in an ini-file (for portability reasons).

But for some reason I am unable to create or write an existing ini-file (reading works perfectly).

### What I've tried so far

- run the application with admin privileges, which works but is not viable all the time
- use `QStandardPath` to ensure a writable path

### MCVE

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QStandardPaths>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation);
    path = path + "/settings.ini";

    QFileInfo info(path);
    qDebug() << info.exists();
    qDebug() << info.isWritable();

    QSettings settings(path, QSettings::IniFormat);
    settings.setValue("key", "value");
    settings.sync();

    return 0;
}
```

### Question

Why does the ini-file only get generated / updated when the application is running with admin privileges? Is there any way to do it without?

Comment: Ensure that `path` exists. It doesn't have to. E.g. add `Q_ASSERT(QDir{path}.exists())`. I can't reproduce this, sorry. It works on both Windows and OS X. You don't need the widget nor `app.exec()` either. This can be using `QCoreApplication` and `#include <QtCore>` - in terms of minimization.

Comment: Whats not working? I could not reproduce any flaw

Comment: Also, ensure that `settings.ini` doesn't exist with privileges that make it unwritable with regular user privileges: `auto file = QStringLiteral("%1/settings.ini").arg(path); Q_ASSERT(QFileInfo{file}.isWritable() || !QFileInfo{file}.exists());

Comment: That's the brick wall I've been running into for the last hours. The ```path``` definitely exists. Running the app without admin privileges just does not create / save the ini-file.

Comment: Use `QFile::isWriteable` before you try to write anything.

Comment: @user3606329 `QFileInfo`, not `QFile`.

Comment: But that shouldn't matter if the file doesn't get created in the first place?

Comment: if you go manually to `path` and create a test file .. then what happens? check what _warnings_ are in _compiler output_ and _application output_?

Comment: I have edited the example once again. It outputs ```false``` twice if the file does not exist and ```true``` if I create an empty ```settings.ini```.

Comment: What Qt version is it, and what compiler you're using, and what's the source for your Qt binary (download vs. self-compiled - which exact one - point to it).

Comment: Okey, for some reason it just does not work on my laptop but on my other PC. I'll try to find it out myself and post the result if I get any.

Comment: Should you not be using QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation instead of QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation ?!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what versions of OS are used. Windows 10 (version 1709) come with new feature called "Protected folders" to prevent e.g. Ransomware threats. You can reconfigure it somewhere. It disallow write access to desktop/documents etc.

But more preferable approach will be to store ini file into other location e.g. AppData.